# SQL to get entry_id in exp_channel_data based on member_id

Tags: safecracker, sql

I have custom channel named `foo` that is connected to the the members via safecracker and safecracker registration.

In a hook I am making, the member_id of a person is available to me.

Is there a way using SQL to get the entry_id in `channel_data` table based on the member_id that I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ct.entry_id 
FROM exp_channel_titles AS ct
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data cd ON ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id 
WHERE ct.author_id = $member_id
```

Although you've requested the entry_id in your question, you don't actually need to include channel_data, as it's in channel_titles. But I've included above in case you want to pull all the entry data (so change `SELECT ct.entry_id` to `SELECT *`)

$member_id in the above would be variable you're searching on.